# Rename Virtual Directory in IIS using VBScript?

Tags: iis, vbscript

How can I rename a Virtual Directory (or Web Application) in IIS 6.0/7.0 using VBScript?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to change the site name in IIS 7. Edit the `applicationHost.config` file.
This file can be found in `c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\`

Find and replace the name of the application. Save the file. And if you restart the IIS Management Console you will see the name has change.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to rename it in IIS, or change the virtual path? adsutil can do either. It should be installed in c:\inetpub\AdminScripts

adsutil.vbs SET W3SVC/*svcnum*/Root/*AppName*/AppFriendlyName "New Friendly Name"
adsutil.vbs SET W3SVC/*svcnum*/Root/*AppName*/AppRoot "New Application Path"

Answer (score 2):

See the "Name" property of the objects from the IIsWebVirtualDirSetting WMI collection (from the MicrosoftIISv2 WMI namespace).

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525005%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to use a local shell script.

Try PowerShell, I think IIS7 has introduced [new administration tools](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/98/using-scripts-to-automate-management/) that look quite powerful. I **think** you could also use these scripts to manage IIS remotely via WMI.

It shouldn't be any more complicated then VBScript.

Another way would be to use VBScript to edit the IIS configuration files or create an [administration object](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/165/how-to-use-microsoftwebadministration/), but that doesn't really seem to be the way to go about it.

Hopefully this helps.