# Rename virtual directory on Windows Server 2008 (IIS7 )

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008

How can I rename a virtual directory (i.e., change the Virtual Path name) in IIS7 on Windows Server 2008?

In Server Manager I click on the application, select Basic Settings, but the box showing the current Alias is greyed out and I can't edit it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For as far as I know, there is no way to do it. You can only delete the virtual directory, and recreate it with the same settings.

Or at least, you can't do it through the GUI. There might be ways to do it through scripting in PowerShell for example. But I don't know how.

Comment: Looks like you're right. No-one else has got any suggestions on doing this via the UI so I guess it's not possible. Still don't know why though.

Comment: This is not true - see the answer by Brian Grinstead, below.

Comment: @Richard Ev
I never said it was impossible, I said I did not know a way to do it. Thus my answer is highly unlikely to be false, or are you suggesting that I *did* know a way to do it? ;-) Furthermore, njr asked for a way to do it with GUI (see Cheesy's answer) not console.

Still, Brian's answer has proven to be valuable obviously. Although in my opinion, it's faster to delete + recreate if you aren't renaming VDs on a regular basis.

Answer (score 62):

I found a way to do this using the built in appcmd.exe tool.  If you wanted to change your virtual directory "Images" inside your application "OldApplicationName" type this into the command line.

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set vdir "Default Web Site/OldApplicationName/Images" -path:/Images2
```

More details, including how to rename applications here: http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/rename-applications-and-virtual-directories-in-iis7/

Answer (score 7):

If you are also trying to rename the app, the context is almost the same except using "set app" instead of "set vdir"

```
appcmd set app "Default Web Site/OriginalSite" -path:/RenamedSite
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to checkout this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264826/rename-virtual-directory-in-iis)

From adilei...

> Try PowerShell, I think IIS7 has
>   introduced new administration tools
>   that look quite powerful. I think you
>   could also use these scripts to manage
>   IIS remotely via WMI.
>
> It shouldn't be any more complicated
>   then VBScript.
>
> Another way would be to use VBScript
>   to edit the IIS configuration files or
>   create an administration object, but
>   that doesn't really seem to be the way
>   to go about it.

and from jwmiller5...

> Do you want to rename it in IIS, or
>   change the virtual path? adsutil can
>   do either. It should be installed in
>   c:\inetpub\AdminScripts
>
> adsutil.vbs SET
>   W3SVC/svcnum/Root/AppName/AppFriendlyName
>   "New Friendly Name" adsutil.vbs SET
>   W3SVC/svcnum/Root/AppName/AppRoot "New
>   Application Path"

Comment: Thanks; I'd already seen the other post. I'm trying to do this via the UI. I don't want to do it programatically. I can't figure out why the box is greyed out. I can't think of any logical reason why I shouldn't be able to rename an application to make it available under a different URL.